# Branch.io smart banner is empty

Tags: branch.io, smartbanner

My team released an Android app and asked for a smart banner directing users from our website to the app and specific content; to complete this task, we are using [branch.io](http://branch.io).

According to this [guide](https://dev.branch.io/features/journeys/guide/), I inserted the JavaScript snippet with the branch key found in the settings section of the dashboard and the SDK is correctly initialized.

In the dashboard we defined the styling of the banner and on which sites and devices it should appear. But the banner looks like this (on desktop):

[image]

No icon or text are set. Apparently when I use the preview link generated by *branch.io* it is displayed correctly.

Moreover when I initialize the banner via JavaScript and set the properties it is displayed correctly too:

```
branch.banner(Banner.options, Banner.data);

const deeplink = `${window.location.pathname}${window.location.search}${window.location.hash}`;

branch.setBranchViewData({
    '$deeplink_path': deeplink
});
```

Somehow nothing from the dashboard is adopted.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: the `branch.banner()` function and the banner you set up on the dashboard are actually separate things. The dashboard option replaced the `banner()` approach, which has been deprecated.

You'll want to review the full details in the [set up guide](https://dev.branch.io/features/journeys/guide/). One important note is that the dashboard version does not yet support banners on desktop, as we found almost none of our partners were using that function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The banner looks like this on Android devices as well.
I followed the guide and integrated the SDK with the correcty key and set the deeplink path, then I switched to the dashboard and did the rest.
Any things I need to look out in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try [smartbanner.js](https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js). Has a lot of custom options and behaviour at very low footprint (~ 13 KB). Takes a few meta tags to set up.